# The sample of in facebook sdk for Android always displays authentication page with language "Bahasa Indonesia"

Tags: android, facebook

I use the android device to run the simple sample project in facebook sdk for android.
The app authentication page is always in language "Bahasa Indonesia".
I have changed language of my android device (English and Chinese), but it still displayed in  language "Bahasa Indonesia".

I use my Browser app in my device to confirm this issue, I opened url http://m.facebook.com in Browser app in my device.
The page also displayed in language "Bahasa Indonesia".

I remember this situation does not happened last week, the authentication page and login page changes its display language based on the language of my device.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

---

Here is some update: 
I am in Taiwan, when I using Chunghwa Telecom ADSL network, it always show Facebook login page in Bahasa Indonesia. I change the device network in 3G mode or other network provider, the login page displays in language where I am.

I am try to see my IP, when the start part of IP is 220.133.X.X, the login page is wrong. IP is 101.10.X.X or 60.245.X.X, the login page displays in correct language.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, it is a facebook bug

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383

Comment: Thank you. Hope this issue can be fixed soon.