# Facebook iOS SDK - Wrong language on auth/login page

Tags: ios, facebook

My current app works with the facebook API and today it started to redirect the user for login on facebook with japanese (or some other oriental language). I'm pretty sure nothing was changed on my code and I've also downloaded the src code from the library again.

Somebody having the same issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Also seeing it here, as of this morning (EST.) Seeing it in all apps, as well as m.facebook.com. Language is Indonesian, apparently. (E.g. "Dapatkan Facebook untuk iPhone dan menjelajah....")

edit:
This is apparently a Facebook-level issue. You can track the status here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383

"On initial login using Facebook, the dialog asking the user to authorize this application is displayed in seemingly random languages.. Only Happens when user is connected over Wifi."

Comment: It's fixed now, according to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue in Android device and iPad.

I also post this issue in here:
 [The sample of in facebook sdk for Android always displays authentication page with language "Bahasa Indonesia"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417979/the-sample-of-in-facebook-sdk-for-android-always-displays-authentication-page-wi)

I am in Taiwan and login page always displayed in Bahasa Indonesia. The network that I am using is Chunghwa Telecom ADSL.

I tried to changed the network provider of my device, e.g. 3G mode or other public wifi service. The login page turns into language as where I am.

I am using this URL http://touch.whatsmyip.org/ to see my IP, when the start part of IP is 220.133.X.X, the login page is wrong.

IP is 101.10.X.X or 60.245.X.X, the login page displays in correct language.