# Facebook in-app showing up in different language

Tags: ios, facebook, localization

I have a very bizarre issue with the facebook-ios-sdk.  Client is complaining about the in-app dialogs showing up in Spanish, when neither their Facebook nor phone is set for spanish.  This is happening across multiple devices and multiple users/accounts.

The Facebook SDK should be pulling the user's language/locale preferences from NSLocale, correct?  Is there a way to set or test this?  Is there some way the language is being set in the HTTP Header Requests for the in-app dialog incorrectly?

(using SSO if it makes a difference)

Thanks,

Comment: It appears to be a system-wide issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438117/facebook-ios-sdk-wrong-language-on-auth-login-page/10453092#10453092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a Facebook-level issue. You can track the status here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383

"On initial login using Facebook, the dialog asking the user to authorize this application is displayed in seemingly random languages.. Only Happens when user is connected over Wifi."

Answer (score 0):

You can check the country code:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *language;
if ([[NSLocale preferredLanguages] count] > 0)
{
    language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
}
else
{
    language = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
}
```